# aurelia-skeleton-navigation - how to properly import jquery-ui into?

Tags: jquery-ui, navigation, aurelia

I have application builded on top of the aurelia-skeleton-navigation. Everything works ok, but can't find solution how to properly import jquery-ui library. Need that one to implement draggable dialog.

I've installed jquery-ui:

```
jspm install jquery-ui
```

Trying to test something as simple as (it's in app.js):

```
import 'jquery-ui';

...

attached() {
  ...
  $("#dialog").dialog();
}
```

Unfortunately, dialog function isn't working. Is it something important that i'm missing? Or perhaps it's little bit more complicated than simple import ...

I'll appreciate any tips.

Comment: Is there any error messages in the console? jquery-ui needs jquery, make sure you're importing jquery first

Comment: Can't see any errors in console. Jquery is ok. I can use (for example) $("#dialog").append('something') in attached and it works fine. Browser stops rendering at the dialog function. Tried to recreate example from here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ESxZA2jTlN7f6aiq1ixG?p=preview on clean aurelia-skeleton starter - but also without success.

Answer (score 0):

my working solution for this was installing a component version of jquery-ui:
https://github.com/components/jqueryui

```
npm install components-jqueryui
jspm install npm:components-jqueryui
```

Then:

```
import { datepicker } from 'components-jqueryui';
attached(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
}
```

And in the view:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Hope this can help.